# How does the TRPO surrogate loss account for the error in the policy?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, papers, policy-gradients, trust-region-policy-optimization

In the [Trust Region Policy Optimization (TRPO) paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.05477.pdf), on page 10, it is stated

> An informal overview is as follows.  Our proof relies on the notion of  coupling,  where  we  jointly  define  the  policies $\pi$ and $\pi'$so  that  they  choose  the  same  action  with  high  probability $(1−\alpha)$.   Surrogate loss $L_π(\hat\pi)$ accounts for the the advantage of $\hat\pi$ the first time that it disagrees with $\pi$,  but not subsequent disagreements. Hence, the error in $L_\pi$ is due to two or more disagreements between $\pi$ and $\hat\pi$, hence, we get an $O(\alpha^2)$ correction term, where $\alpha$ is the probability of disagreement.

I don't see how this holds? In what way does $L_\pi$ account for one disagreement? Surely when $\hat\pi$ disagrees with $\pi$ you will have different trajectories under expectation for each so then $L_\pi$ immediately is different from $\eta$ ?

I understand the proof given, but I wanted to try and capture this intuition.